# Angle between three vector points

Tags: c#

I have three vector points where i want to get the angle of one of the vertices.
I tried to use the law of cosines - cos C = (a² + b² - c²)/2ab, but i get non accurate results.Here is my GetAngle() method

```
public static float GetAngle(Vector2 vec1, Vector2 vec2, Vector2 vec3)
{
    float lenghtA = Mathf.Sqrt(vec1.x * vec1.x + vec1.y * vec1.y);
    float lenghtB = Mathf.Sqrt(vec2.x * vec2.x + vec2.y * vec2.y);
    float lenghtC = Mathf.Sqrt(vec3.x * vec3.x + vec3.y * vec3.y);

    float calc = ((lenghtA * lenghtA) + (lenghtB * lenghtB) - (lenghtC * lenghtC)) / (2 * lenghtA * lenghtB);

    return Mathf.Acos(calc) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}
```

Given that i insert the three vectors:

```
vec1 = new Vector2(1,1);
vec2 = new Vector2(1,5);
vec3 = new Vector2(5,5);
```

Where i want to find the angle of vec3 respectively:

Result: NaN, then when i start moving the vectors i get sometimes inverted angles sometimes again NaN.Its hard to me to observe and inspect what is happening but i was thinking did i get the formula and coding right?

Edit: Observing more when i move vec1 to position (1,5) i get 90 degrees, further to position (1,10) i get 40 degrees..

Comment: The length in the law of cosines are the lengths of the edges of the triangle, but you are calculating the distance of each point of the triangle from the origin.

Comment: so my guess is i have to: lenghtA = (vec3.x - vec2.x, vec3.y - vec2.y)

Comment: Yeah, just be careful with the three subtractings that you'll end up with that you treat the correct ones as A, B and C!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes thanks to Rawling i successfully implemented the method:
Here is the code:

```
  public static float GetAngle(Vector2 vec1, Vector2 vec2, Vector2 vec3)
    {
        float lenghtA = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vec2.x - vec1.x, 2) + Mathf.Pow(vec2.y - vec1.y,2));
        float lenghtB = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vec3.x - vec2.x,2) + Mathf.Pow(vec3.y - vec2.y, 2));
        float lenghtC = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(vec3.x - vec1.x,2) + Mathf.Pow(vec3.y - vec1.y, 2));

        float calc = ((lenghtA * lenghtA) + (lenghtB * lenghtB) - (lenghtC * lenghtC)) / (2 * lenghtA * lenghtB);

        return Mathf.Acos(calc) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    }
```

works like a charm now..